# Fix an Element to a position within a parent scrollable Div

Tags: html, css

This should be rather simple but position: fixed and position absolute do not work!

code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="jqueryUIProgressBar"></div>
    <!-- dynamic content -->   
    <div></div>
    ... ... ...
    <div></div>
</div>
```

this div is about 300px in height, and the content inside is vertically scrollable. The progress bar appears at the top of the div when scrolled right to the top as expected.

But when scrolling down, I would still like the progress bar to appear at the top of the div!

[image]

When i scroll down the progress bar scrolls with the rest of the content!

I want it to stay where it is at the top!

ive tried:

```
#jQueryProgressBar {
    position: fixed
}
```

along with position:absolute, left:0, top:0, float:left ALL SORTS

Just some quick help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `position: fixed` and then set `top` and `left` as well, like this: (untested, should work)

```
#jQueryProgressBar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px; /*change*/
  left: 100px; /*change*/
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, i feel stupid now;) hahaa One problem though. Rather than putting it left:0 right:0 in relation to the parent div, its done it in relation to the page, the the progress bar is now at the top of the page. Any ideas on how to make it inhert the position from its parent div?

Comment: Set `position:relative` on the parent. ;)