# Fixed and relative elements within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-position

I'm trying to position a fixed element WITHIN a div (not the whole page) in my [website](http://violetoeuvre.com/).

I want the navigation (deadspin, gawer, awl, other) to be fixed within the writing section so that even when user scrolls, the nav is still there. But currently it's fixed for the whole page.

As you can see [on my test page](http://violetoeuvre.com/scroll.html), the navigation is fixed the way I want it to be.

I tried messing around with `position:relative`/`position:fixed` for the `#small-box-links` but that doesn't help.

```css
.home_writing {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: left;
}

#small-box-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: rgba(10, 200, 10, 0);
  width: 980px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#small-box-links {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 700px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="small-box-container">
  <div id="small-box-links">
    <a href="#small-box1" class="top_link_style">deadspin |</a>
    <a href="#small-box2" class="top_link_style">gawker |</a>
    <a href="#small-box3" class="top_link_style">the awl |</a>
    <a href="#small-box4" class="top_link_style">other</a>
  </div>
  <div style='overflow:hidden; width:980px;'>
    <div style='overflow:scroll; width:988px'>
      <div id="small-box1" class="small-box">
        <h2>deadspin</h2>
        <h3>How Pat Summitt Ruined The Best Thing About Women's Basketball</h3>
<!-- etc. for other boxes -->
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6872665) related question and yet when I try top / left, etc., the element is still fixed to the page, not writing div. (I tried making the parent element, `.home_writing`, relative but this doesn't fix my issue.)

(On another note, I can't figure out why my Playfair in the paragraphs doesn't look like the sidebar navigation. It's styled the same way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` always uses the viewport as the frame of reference, so you can’t use that here.

But the solution is rather simple - use `position:absolute` instead to position the navigation inside a container element that has `position:relative` (and a fixed height), and then have the content as a sibling inside that container as well, with fixed height and `overflow:auto` for that element:

```
<div style="position:relative; height:800px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; top:0; …"> [link link link] </div>
  <div style="height:800px; overflow:auto;">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit …
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! This is starting to make sense, but I'm not sure which elements you're referring to. 

So, the #small-box-container has position:relative, #small-box-links should have absolute? (This is all in html?) Then I should delete any conflicting styles in css?

Comment: or, do the styles you indicate refer to the div that contains the #small-box1, 2 ,3, 4, and .small-box below?

Comment: I posted the(/a) _general_ solution – adapting it to your code is your job ;-) And of course I’m not propagating the use of inline styles here, that was just for the example.

Comment: ha, ok, I have been doing my best to learn but I'm quite quite new to coding. Would you just give me a hint if you are referring to the #small-box-container and #small-box-links or the content divs below? And, are you saying I should just just CSS styles, not inline styles? (My impression is that inline is also inelegant).

Comment: I got it!! Just by adding position:absolute to the #small-box-links in the CSS. Thanks again.